# Drawn rectangle on pdf not rendered immediately

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using PDFTron to write some text and draw some shapes on a pdf page.
My problem is, when I draw a rectangle on a page and I open the newly saved pdf document, it can be seen that my drawn rectangle is rendered about half second after I opened the PDF.

```
private void DrawRectangle(ElementWriter writer)
{
    var rect = new Rect(290, 520, 370, 535);
    var elemBuilder = new ElementBuilder();
    elemBuilder.PathBegin();
    var rectX = rect.x1;
    var rectY = rect.y1;
    elemBuilder.Rect(rectX, rectY, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
    var element = elemBuilder.PathEnd();

    // Set the path color space and color
    var gstate = element.GetGState();
    gstate.SetStrokeColorSpace(ColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB());
    gstate.SetStrokeColor(new ColorPt(255, 255, 255));
    gstate.SetFillColor(new ColorPt(255, 255, 255));
    element.SetPathStroke(false);
    element.SetPathFill(true);

    writer.WritePlacedElement(element);
}
```

Is there any solution for this problem?